# opencv: CV_8SC1 vs CV_8UC1 - are negative values mapped to/treated as 0?

Tags: opencv

I want to manipulate gray images using opencv.

I wonder if CV_8SC1 and CV_8UC1 just use different representations and are otherwise equivalent.

Ie. is the gray range mapped 1:1 from -128..127 for CV_8SC1 to 0..255 for CV_8UC1?

According to my experiments, it seems negative values aren't mapped at all, and the resulting gray range provided by CV_8SC1 is only the bottom half of the range provided by CV_8UC1,

I'm using opencv via Java, so I'm not entirely sure if my results aren't only because of how the Java<->C/C++ conversion goes.

Comment: What do you mean `is the gray range mapped` ? Do you mean with `convertTo` function? if this is the case, it uses saturateCast durng conversion, that means, all negative values are clamped to 0 and the other way, all values above 127 are clamped to 127. You can always convert it to 16S add 127 to have everything positive and convert it to 8U to obtain the correct result. Not sure in Java but in C++ you can access a value with `at` and say at that moment how to interpret the data, e.g. mat.at<uchar> or mat.at<char>

Comment: That sounds like what happens when I call imwrite() on 8S data.